# Combine dependent IObservables

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm having trouble to combine two Observables which are dependent (meaning the result of one sequence is needed as input for the other).

I have 2 methods:

- Method 1 returns an `IObservable<List<Message>>`
- Method 2 returns an `IObservable<ExtraInfoOfMessage>` (with input parameter `Message`)

For every message returned by method 1 I have to execute method 2 and add the result to the Message object.

I know there are methods like `CombineLatest`, `Zip`, etc... . But it seems to me that all these methods combine sequences which are not dependent (meaning the result of one sequence is not needed to be able to execute the second sequence).

Is this possible with `IObservables`? Could someone give me a start on how to tackle this?

Comment: why does the second method (method 2) have to be a separate IObservable implementation?

Comment: The retrieval of the message  data is done through third party webservices. So method 1 and 2 just corresponds to a webservice. Now I want to combine these two methods through observables to return all message data at once.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I've understood, your signatures look like this:

```
IObservable<List<Message>> Method1()

IObservable<ExtraInfoOfMessage> Method2(Message parameter)
```

And, your message looks like this:

```
public class Message
{
    public ExtraInfoOfMessage ExtraInfoOfMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
Func<Message, ExtraInfoOfMessage, Message> combine = (m, e) =>
{
    m.ExtraInfoOfMessage = e;
    return m;
};

IObservable<Message> query =
    from messages in Method1()
    from message in messages
    from extra in Method2(message)
    select combine(message, extra);
```

If you want your query to return a list of messages then do this:

```
IObservable<IList<Message>> query =
(
    from messages in Method1()
    from message in messages
    from extra in Method2(message)
    select combine(message, extra)
).ToList();
```